# CanvasJS switching of graphs

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Please help,

I need a switching of graphs in canvasjs using ajax. My datapoints comes from the json format. For example, Line Chart - Pie Chart - Bar Chart like vice versa.

Thank you very much for your help. Just show me how to do it.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

CanvasJS supports dynamic updates of chart-options. Please take a look at the following example that shows rendering multi-series chart from json and changing chart-type based on drop-down value.

```js
var dps1 = [], dps2 = [];
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {            
  title: {
    text: "MultiSeries Chart from JSON"
  },
  animationEnabled: true,
  toolTip: {    
    shared: true
  },
  data: [
    {
   type: "spline",
      dataPoints: dps1
    },
    {
   type: "spline",
      dataPoints: dps2
    }
  ]
});
        
$.when(
    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/zb96f", function(data) {      
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          dps1.push({ label: data[i].label, y: data[i].y1 });
            dps2.push({ label: data[i].label, y: data[i].y2 });            
          }
      })
    ).then(function() {
    chart.render();
 }); 
 
var chartType = document.getElementById('chartType');
chartType.addEventListener( "change",  function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < chart.options.data.length; i++){
     chart.options.data[i].type = chartType.options[chartType.selectedIndex].value;
   }
   chart.render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<br/><!-- Just so that JSFiddle's Result label doesn't overlap the Chart -->   

<div>Chart Type:
  <select id="chartType" name="Chart Type">
    <option value="line">Line</option>
    <option value="column">Column</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="stackedColumn">Stacked Column</option>
    <option value="stackedBar">Stacked Bar</option>
  </select>  
</div>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
```